# how to move multiple objects into the centre of a circle

Tags: edges, scale

[image]

Hi. Is there anyway that you can move multiple objects in to the center of them in a proportional way but not using scaling up and down?

I want to make it like the below but maintaining their proportion. I tried grab each of edges of them toward inwards and hit "G" and moved but I doesn't work like "S" key and scaled down.
[image]

Same Problem with edge slide
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My apologies for the fast gifs, but one way since the spokes are separate objects is to create one and offset it's Y axis if you need to (but you don't have to).

[image]

Then set the cursor to a center point in object mode and rotate the objects around it (alt + d).

[image]

Select one object and go into edit mode. Select the tip of the spoke and drag using the Y axis. It will maintain it's size and go towards the center.

[image]

Then you can make the objects one object (ctrl + j).

EDIT: Just found an even faster way if all objects are combined and you're selecting ONLY the edges...
Simply:  (Alt + s)

Comment: Can you please show that by animation? I'm using 2.79b and cannot duplicate your instructions to achieve the same effect. If we were resizing it that would be fine. But it doesn't seem to work for simply moving it along the axis?

Comment: Have done.. but of course, Alt S. I keep forgetting it doesn't need a face normal.

Answer (score 2):

If you do want to do this in Edit Mode, on a single object, it is possible, in this case.

- Set Transform Orientation to 'Normal'
- Set Pivot to 'Individual Origins'
- Select all the inner edges, (the ones you want to move)
- Hit <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>

(<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> will make the spokes more or less tapered)

[image]

I've added the Blend in response to @Monolith .. we seem to have anomalous behaviour...

[image]

Comment: I think you mean G + Z + Z

Comment: @Monolith Ahhh.. I've selected _edges_, not faces. These are just plane faces.  In Edge  space, Y is along the edge, X at right-angles to that. You've selected Faces? (or enough edges to make them?), so the direction you're interested in is Z?

Comment: Well you're obviously doing it, but I'm not sure how. Lol No matter what I do, it doesn't react like that. I'm at: Edit Mode>Solid>Individual Origins>Normal Orientation>Face Select. GXX. I would ask for the blend, but this is not our thread. Lol Might DM you.

Comment: Ohhh it's what I thought. You were using flat polygons which yeah- gives a single axis for the edge. For a 3D object it doesn't seem to perform the same way.